# Android,Force Close on clicking the dialog button

Tags: android, forceclose, dialog

I am trying to start another activity from the dialog box, however I'm getting this force close if I run in an emulator. How to fix this?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boolean firstrun= true;
    if (firstrun) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("This is First Run !").setMessage("Welcome! Please enter the emergency numbers!");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent sv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.sach.droidclinic.Save.class);
                startActivity(sv);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialogue = builder.create();
        dialogue.show();
    }
```

This the log cat i have attached along with the question,

```
11-10 21:48:58.250: D/dalvikvm(410): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 53% free 2543K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 107ms
11-10 21:49:24.450: D/AndroidRuntime(410): Shutting down VM
11-10 21:49:24.450: W/dalvikvm(410): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sach.droidclinic/com.sach.droidclinic.Save}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.sach.droidclinic.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-10 21:49:24.469: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 21:50:01.749: D/dalvikvm(440): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 53% free 2543K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 216ms
11-10 21:50:08.658: D/AndroidRuntime(440): Shutting down VM
11-10 21:50:08.658: W/dalvikvm(440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sach.droidclinic/com.sach.droidclinic.Save}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.sach.droidclinic.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-10 21:50:08.689: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 21:51:12.799: D/dalvikvm(469): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 53% free 2543K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 108ms
11-10 21:51:18.382: D/AndroidRuntime(469): Shutting down VM
11-10 21:51:18.389: W/dalvikvm(469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sach.droidclinic/com.sach.droidclinic.Save}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.sach.droidclinic.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @user2971347 post your logcat error also.

Comment: No need to tag user in his question. Because question owner will automatically get the notification @SathishKumar

Comment: `11-10 21:51:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
`

Comment: I cannot post whole the log cat as a comment, so im posting as a answer to this question, Sorry im newbee here !

Comment: log cat is clearly stating that you have not declared Save Activity in manifest. have you?

Comment: I do  have declared Save activity in manifest ...

Comment: Yes , I needed to change some code in manifest and my app ran ! Thank you so much everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

replace this in on click

```
Intent sv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.sach.droidclinic.Save.class);
                startActivity(sv);
```

with

```
Intent sv = new Intent(YourActivityName.this,com.sach.droidclinic.Save.class);
                startActivity(sv);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I tried it, Still im having the same problem, my app is like this, I have a splash screen for 2500milisec and then dialog appears, (that splash will lead to main activity though)  i need to invoke another activty from the positive button of dialog.

Comment: post your mainfest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boolean firstrun= true;
    if (firstrun) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("This is First Run !").setMessage("Welcome! Please enter the emergency numbers!");
        AlertDialog dialogue = builder.create();
        dialogue.show();
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent sv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.sach.droidclinic.Save.class);
                startActivity(sv);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help , but the above code will not display any action button in the dialog box

Answer (score 0):

stack trace show an activityNotFoundException. look again in your manifest file and make sure that you declare activity com.sach.droidclinic.Save there.